# How to create master page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, master-page, web-application, visual-studio-2012

I've designed a web application in ASP.Net/VB.Net in Visual Studio 2012. I want to deploy this in SharePoint 2013.

I've read many blogs from Internet, one answer I frequently found is: Open master page from master page gallery and download a copy then make changes and publish. If I download a copy of master page then the code is in SharePoint, but my web application code is in VB.Net. Is there any way to do this? Can anyone suggest me how to deploy in SharePoint?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You mean say You would like to customize master page with webpart of which coding is in VB.Net.

Comment: yes Viraj how to do that

Comment: Simple is that recreate SharePoint solution. Create custom master page(Copy of SharePoint master page). Create visual web part. Replace your code in webpart. If you want to add webpart in master page. You can register with <%Register.

Answer (score 1):

There is no any issue of using a different language (VB.NET) master page in SharePoint.

The SharePoint Server comes with a Publishing feature as an out of the box component so that you can use its rich functionalities to build and deploy custom branded sites using master pages, layout pages etc. **These functionalities are not available out of the box in SharePoint Foundation.**

The [SharePoint Foundation 2013 Publishing Infrastructure](https://spf2013publishing.codeplex.com/) aims at bringing a stripped down version of the SharePoint Server Publishing functionality to SharePoint Foundation 2013. It provides the site publishing features to the SharePoint Foundation platform. By using its features one can easily create and maintain a custom branded site using SharePoint Designer in SharePoint Foundation.

If you want to **deploy your custom master page** than please follow [these steps](http://frederik.se/how-to-deploy-a-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/) after deploying above mentioned solution.

Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Hi Hardik the above example is like creating new site collection but I have done already with the web application my question how to add that to share point

Comment: You miss read the whole answer. As you are using SharePoint Foundation so publishing feature will no more available in it. So you need to deploy  "SharePoint Foundation 2013 Publishing Infrastructure" from codeplex first. so you will get publishing feature in your farm. than after you need to deploy your custom master page using given steps in http://frederik.se/how-to-deploy-a-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/